# Keep getting "Index out of range" error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, array, runtime-error

So I primarily use java and C++ and VBA is very new to me. I'm very confused as to why I keep getting error 9 - "Index out of range". Here is the code:

```
Dim count As Integer
Dim j As Integer

count = months.count

Dim monthsArr() As String
ReDim monthsArr(1, count)

For j = 1 To count
    monthsArr(j) = months.Item(j)
Next j
```

Count is equal to 10 (I checked with a msgBox) and so months is an ArrayList of length 10. I'm trying to put the values of months into an array so I can use that array on an autofilter. I keep getting an error at this line:

```
monthsArr(j) = months.Item(j)
```

I thought VBA used 1-indexing for collections but I really don't know. Anybody know why I keep getting this error? Thanks

Comment: What type is months? Perhaps it's months that is zero-indexed? If so, you'd want `monthsArr(j) = months.Item(j-1)`

Comment: "Dim months As ArrayList" is what I used to declare it. It is an Arraylist containing strings.

Comment: So what is the value of `j` when it fails?

Comment: "I thought VBA used 1-indexing for collections but I really don't know" - why not just test it?

Answer (score 3):

You have re-dimensioned `monthsArr` to be a 2-dimension array `ReDim monthsArr(1, count)`.
If it should remains a 2-dimension array, then when you assign elements to it, you must also show which part of the array on both dimension. You are only using one: `monthsArr(j) = months.Item(j)`. It should be something like `monthsArr(j,i) = months.Item(j)` where `i` is the second dimension of the array.

Also, note that 0 is the first in an array, not 1. So when you declare `monthsArr(1,count)`, it means that the first dimension has 2 elements/items while the second dimension will have count + 1 elements.

If it is not meant to be a 2-diension array but a 1-dimension array, then you should use: `ReDim monthsArr(count)` or `ReDim monthsArr(count-1)` as the its 0-based.

Comment: Thanks so much. This really helped. I meant to make a 1-dimensional array, not a 2 dimensional array. Rookie mistake I guess haha.

Comment: Follow the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [this](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) on how to say thank you on this site.